# Multiple bibliographies without bibtex and citations

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing an article where I am using section wise bibliography (I am not using bibtex). The code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

% Save old cite/bibitem command(s)
\let\oldcite\cite
\let\oldtextcite\textcite % Add others as needed
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem

% Add new counter to increment at each paper
\newcounter{papernum}
\def\nextpaper{\stepcounter{papernum}}

% Define new cite/bibitem command(s) with prefix applied
\def\mynewcite#1{\oldcite{\thepapernum#1}}%
\def\mynewtextcite#1{\oldtextcite{\thepapernum#1}}%
\def\mynewbibitem#1{\oldbibitem{\thepapernum#1}}%

% Reroute original commands to new commands
\let\cite\mynewcite%
\let\textcite\mynewtextcite%
\let\bibitem\mynewbibitem%

\section*{Paper 1}\nextpaper %This could be wrapped into whatever unit you use to start a new paper; just make sure another sectioning command (in this case, References is also a \section*) doesn't increment the counter in places you don't want it to.
Ipsum \cite{ipsum}, % I want this to produce the text '[1]', since it is number 1 in this paper's bibliography.
Dolor \cite{dolor}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{ipsum} Ipsum
\bibitem{dolor} Dolor
\end{thebibliography}

\section*{Paper 2}\nextpaper
Lorem \cite{lorem}, Ipsum \cite{ipsum}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{lorem} Lorem
\bibitem{ipsum} Ipsum
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

It works well, but when I write for section (Paper 2)  say `\cite{lorem,ipsum}` it shows [1,?]. How can I get multiple citations with `\cite` command in this case?

Comment: Welcome! Great first question ;). I'd recommend modifying your example so that it actually reproduces the problem i.e. so it produces `[1,7]` or whatever when it shouldn't.

Comment: Although I have no idea why you want to reinvent the wheel in a new square shape.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you wish to use square wheels, but, since you do, perhaps something like this would suit:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Add new counter to increment at each paper
\newcounter{papernum}
\def\nextpaper{\stepcounter{papernum}}

% Save old bibitem command(s)
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\def\mynewbibitem#1{\oldbibitem{\thepapernum#1}}
\let\bibitem\mynewbibitem

\makeatletter
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\thepapernum\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section*{Paper 1}\nextpaper %This could be wrapped into whatever unit you use to start a new paper; just make sure another sectioning command (in this case, References is also a \section*) doesn't increment the counter in places you don't want it to.
Ipsum \cite{ipsum}, % I want this to produce the text '[1]', since it is number 1 in this paper's bibliography.
Dolor \cite{dolor}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{ipsum} Ipsum
\bibitem{dolor} Dolor
\end{thebibliography}

\section*{Paper 2}\nextpaper
Lorem \cite{lorem}, Ipsum \cite{ipsum}
Lorem and Ipsum \cite{lorem,ipsum}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{lorem} Lorem
\bibitem{ipsum} Ipsum
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result of the square wheels defined in the code:

[image: bibliography and citations using square wheels]

Comment: Thanks for the code. It is working well. I do not have any intention to reinvent the wheel in square shape :) , but this particular format is really needed as I am not using the bibtex   and every time you can't give only one citation. Cheers :)

Comment: @SayanBiswas I really meant: BibTeX or Biblatex/Biber - especially Biblatex - already have this kind of thing honed to a fine art. So it seems *prima facie* perverse to invent a solution from scratch ....